# SQL Server bulk insert issue

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012, windows-services, bulkinsert

I have a windows service running each 5 seconds and this service just call a stored procedure in a SQL Server database, this stored procedures executes a bulk insert like this:

```
BULK INSERT #temp_table
FROM '\\path_to_csv.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR =  '0x0a',
     KEEPNULLS,
     TABLOCK);
```

I realize that the temp table get outdated values instead of getting fresh values of the CSV file.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: what do you mean it gets outdated values from the csv? Is the csv getting overwritten? Why every 5 seconds?

Comment: yes the csv is getting overwritten because they are gps positions but the bulk insert  get always the same values

Comment: how long does it take the proc to execute? and again, why every 5 seconds?

Comment: it takes 0 seconds is really fast and 5 seconds because I need to store these gps data to a historic table